# c# reflection current of runtime parameter values

Tags: c#, reflection

For some debug code I'm writing Trace code I'm trying to output the name of the method using `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ToString()` but I also wanted to output the current methods parameter names and values. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the parameter *names* (and types, modifiers, attributes etc) via [`MethodBase.GetParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getparameters.aspx) but you can't get the *values* that way. You may want to consider using some form of AOP (such as [Postsharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/)) to add logging for parameter values.

Comment: i'm wondering what you don know in c# ? ?? is there any thing left to understand for u ??